# Using python sockets to connect bluetooth device

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, pybluez

I'm trying to connect to custom bluetooth device with sockets using python. I use pybluez to find device and get it's address. Current code looks like this:

```
import bluetooth, subprocess
import socket

class BCI(object):
    """
    Bluetooth Connection to BCI
    """
    socket_ = None
    bluetooth_address = None
    connected = False
    port = 0x005
    dev_name = None

    cmds = {}
        

    status = {
        0:  'ok',
        1:  'communication timeout',
        3:  'checksum error',
        4:  'unknown command',
        5:  'invalid access level',
        8:  'hardware error',
        10: 'device not ready',
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bluetooth_address = kwargs.get("bluetooth_address", None)
        if self.bluetooth_address is None:
            self.find()

    def connect(self):
        try:         
            self.socket_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
            #self.socket_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET, socket.BTPROTO_L2CAP)
            self.socket_.connect((self.bluetooth_address, self.port))
            self.connected = True
        except:
            self.socket_.close()
            self.connected = False
            raise ConnectionError

    def find(self):
        dev = self.__class__.__name__
        print('Searching for ' + dev)
        nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True)
        for index, val in enumerate(nearby_devices):
            addr, name = val
            if dev in name.upper():
                self.dev_name = name
                self.bluetooth_address = addr
                print('Found BCI: ' + name + ' @', self.bluetooth_address)
                return
        
    def find_bluetooth_services(self):
        services = bluetooth.find_service(address=self.bluetooth_address)
        if len(services) > 0:
            print("found %d services on %s" % (len(services), self.bluetooth_address))
            print(services)
        else:
            print("no services found")
            
    def close(self):
        self.socket_.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        device = BCI()
    except:
        print('No devices BCI found')
    
    try:
        print("Trying to connect with "+ device.__class__.__name__)
        device.connect()
    except ConnectionError:
        print ('Can\'t connect with ' + device.__class__.__name__)
    '''    
    try:
        device.find_bluetooth_services()
    except:
        print("Some problem occured")
    '''
    
    if device.connected:
        print('Connected {}'.format(device.dev_name)+ device.__class__.__name__ +'  @', device.bluetooth_address)
```

It founds device and tries to connect (terminal output):

Searching for BCI
Found BCI: BCI-2016-SN005 @ 00:80:E1:BE:EE:F1
Trying to connect with BCI

,so there is a notification from settings demanding approve the connection with the some number code. After I approve connection, this gets out (terminal output):

Can't connect with BCI

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use connect_ex() instead of connect() and got this error code 10065, but couldn't find out what it means in context of bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

I just used wrong port number, shoud've been used port = 1

Comment: Do you have any advice for figuring out what port a bluetooth device is using?

Comment: @Brionius, I just tried different options, in my case, it was just matter of luck